# convert Double Inner Join SQl query to LINQ

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL Query and want to convert it into LINQ statement And I never work with Linq Statements before please help me with this Thanks

```
SELECT c.* , v.*
  FROM UserEnrolleds u
  INNER JOIN Courses c ON u.CourseId = c.id
  INNEr JOIN Videos v ON v.CourseID = c.Id
  WHERE u.UsersID = '8851d572-eaff-4a84-9ec8-aa144fecfea2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have three tables: Courses, Videos, and UserEnrolleds.

There is a relation between Courses and UserEnrolleds, probably a one-to-many relation: every Course has zero or more UserEnrolleds, every UserEnrolled belongs to exactly one Course, namely the Course with the Course.Id that the foreign key UserEnrolled.CourseId points to.

Similarly there seems to be a one-to-many relation between Videos and Courses: every Video has a foreign key Video.CourseId to the Course that it belongs to.

It seems to me, that you want the Courses and the Videos that are enrolled by a user with Id "8851d572-eaff..."

You planned to do this using an inner join of UserEnrolleds - Courses - Videos.

If you use Entity Framework there are two methods you can use for it. You can use the `virtual ICollection` properties, or do the join yourself.

Usually I find the use of the `ICollection` easier, and more appealing, but let's first focus on your question.

### Full inner join on three tables

For this I'll use one of the overloads of [Queryable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.join?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var result = dbContext.UserEnrolleds          // get table UserEnrolleds

    // keep only the UserEnrolleds with the mentioned UsersId:
    .Where(userEnrolled => userEnrolled.UsersId = "8851...")

    .Join(dbContext.Courses,                  // join with table Courses,
    userEnrolled => userEnrolled.CourseId,    // from every userEnrolled take the CourseId
    course => course.Id,                      // from every course take the Id

    (userEnrolled, Course) => new             // remember the matching items for the next join
    {
        UserEnrolled = userEnrolled,
        Course = Course,
    })

    .Join(dbContext.Videos,              // join with the Videos table
    joinResult => joinResult.Course.Id,  // from the previous Join take the Course Id
    video => video.CourseId,             // from the video take the CourseId

    (joinResult, video) => new           // when they match, make one new object
    {
       UserEnrolled => joinResult.UserEnrolled,
       Course => joinResult.Course,
       Video => video,
    })
```

After the join, use a Select to query only the properties you actually plan to use.

```
.Select(joinResult => new
{
    Course = new
    {
        Id = joinResult.Course.Id,
        Name = joinResult.Course.Name,
        ...
    },

    Video = new
    {
        Id = joinResult.Video.Id,
        Name = joinResult.Video.Name,
        ...
    }

    UserEnrolled = ...
});
```

If you want to query the complete Course and Video:

```
.Select(joinResult => new
{
     Course = joinResult.Course,
     Video = joinResult.Video,
})
```

Be aware though that you will be transferring several properties that you probably won't use, especially the foreign keys.

Of course you could do the select in the last parameter of the join (resultSelector). I didn't do this, to make it easier to understand.

### Use the virtual ICollection

Quite often, if you have a one-to-many relation, you want to do a GroupJoin instead of a Join: you want all "Courses with their Videos".

So instead of a table:

```
Course 1 - Video 10
Course 1 - Video 11
Course 1 - Video 12
Course 2 - Video 13
Course 2 - Video 14
Course 3 - Video 15
```

You want a table:

```
Course 1 with its Videos 10, 11, and 12
Course 2 with its Videos 13, and 14
Course 3 with its one and only Video 15
Course 4 has no Video at all.
```

If you prefer "Courses with their Videos" (and maybe also something with the UserEnrolleds), it is way easier to use the `virtual ICollection`, instead of doing the join yourself.

If you followed the [entity framework code first conventions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), you'll have classes similar to the following:

```
class Course
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Course has zero or more Videos:
    public virtual ICollection<Video> Videos {get; set;}

    // Every Course has zero or more UserEnrolleds:
    public virtual ICollection<UserEnrolled> UserEnrolleds {get; set;}
}

public class Video
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ...

    // every Video belongs to exactly one Course, using foreign key:
    public int CourseId {get; set;}
    public virtual Course Course {get; set;}
}
```

UserEnrolled is similar to video:

```
public class UserEnrolled
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string UsersId {get; set;}
    ...

    // every Video belongs to exactly one Course, using foreign key:
    public int CourseId {get; set;}
    public virtual Course Course {get; set;}
}
```

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by the non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

The foreign keys are real columns in your tables, hence they are non-virtual

For completeness the DbContext:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Course> Courses {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Video> Videos {get; set;}
    public DbSet<UserEnrolled> UserEnrolleds {get; set;}
}
```

This is all that entity framework needs to know to detect your tables, the columns in your tables, and the relations between them. It will also create and use the primary keys and the foreign keys for you.

Now to get all Courses, each with their Videos, that are enrolled by the user with Id "8851d572-eaff..." (= that have at least one UserEnrolled with a UsersId equal to "8851d572-eaff..."), use the following query:

```
var coursesAndVideosEnrolledByUser = dbContext.Courses

    // keep only the Courses that are enrolled by user with Id "8851..."
    .Where(course => course.UserEnrolleds
                     .Any(userEnrolled => userEnrolled.UsersId = "8851d572-eaff..."))
    .Select(course => new
    {
        Id = course.Id,
        Name = course.Name,
        ...

        Videos = course.Videos,
    });
```

Do you agree that this looks much more natural if you want to get Courses, each with their Videos, attended by a certain User?

Bonus point: if there are Courses attended by this user that has no Videos, you'll still get them in your result. You won't get them using an Inner join!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming variable db is your database try;

```
var qdResult = 
    from u in db.UserEnrolleds 
        join c in db.Courses on u.CourseID equals c.id 
        join v in db.Videos on c.Id equals v.CourseID
    where u.UsersID = '8851d572-eaff-4a84-9ec8-aa144fecfea2'
    select c, v
```